# databricks rest api weird missing parameter

Tags: python, azure, rest, databricks, azure-databricks

I have noticed, there is [an unanswered question](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12912/rest-api-clusterscreate-missing-required-parameter.html) about getting the weird response from azure databricks rest api 2.0 while trying to create a cluster.

```
error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE', 'message': 'Missing required field: size'
```

**Has anyone solved this issue? Is there a new API? Or some bugs in it?**

I actually used an example from [ms databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples#--create-a-python-3-cluster-databricks-runtime-55-and-below) and I had to change several things, but I used

```
"autoscale": {
              "min_workers": 2,
              "max_workers": 8
                }
```

I thought this weird error might be related to it, so I set num_workers, it also lead to the same issue.

Other changes I had to made

- I used plain token string with no coding (it did not worked with
  coding).
- I used `headers={"Authorization":  "Bearer %s" % (TOKEN)}`
  otherwise there was a error abotu header.
- Also I used `(response.content)` instead of trying to read error from json
  `response.json()["error_code"]`, it caused an error (I didnt go deep
  into it, I just needed the message, what went wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I don't know if it is a valid approach, but this actually creates clusters pragmatically on my azure databricks resource. along with previous changes I have mentioned above I additionally just removed `"new_cluster"` (see example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples#--create-a-python-3-cluster-databricks-runtime-55-and-below)) and

```
response = requests.post(
        'https://%s/api/2.0/clusters/create' % (DOMAIN),
        headers={"Authorization":  "Bearer %s" % (TOKEN)},
        json={
                "cluster_name": name.lower().strip(),
                "spark_version": "6.2.x-scala2.11",
                "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2",
                "spark_env_vars": {
                    "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
                },
                "spark_conf": {
                    "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "serverless",
                    "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages": "sql,python,r"
                },
                "autoscale": {
                    "min_workers": 2,
                    "max_workers": 8
                },
                "ssh_public_keys": [],
                "autotermination_minutes":50
        }
    )
```